# CSS problem with background-attachment:fixed;

Tags: css, background

I have a Joomla site that i have created a custom theme. The site is http://esn.teipir.gr/.

I have two images right and left that i want them to have background image fixed.

I use the following CSS rules

```
div.backgroundboxleft {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url("/images/back_1.png");
    float: left;
    height: 822px;
    top: 40px;
    width: 457px;
}
```

and

```
div.backgroundboxright {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url("/images/back_2.png");
    float: right;
    height: 822px;
    top: 40px;
    width: 457px;
}
```

If i remove the background-attachment all is OK with the images but when i add with firebug the following code everything messes up.Can you help me making the pages stay fixed without the background color being on top of the image?

Thanks

Comment: I forked your code (http://jsfiddle.net/f8HxS/) and played around with it, but can't seem to find any problems with FF. Have you tested it in other browsers, or is only FF giving you this problem?

Comment: See what i mean here 
http://i56.tinypic.com/16m7yhd.jpg and here http://i53.tinypic.com/dwoolk.jpg

Comment: Double check your background at a lower resolution. On my screen (1366x768), when I scroll sideways, it appears that `back_1.png` also includes `back_2.png`, and that `back_2.png` is simply overlaid on top of it. Check it out. http://jsfiddle.net/f8HxS/1/embedded/result/

Comment: One minor thing I should add: when coding CSS for classes, a `.` before the class name will do. For example, `div.backgroundboxright` can be shortened to `.backgroundboxright`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you set `background-attachment:fixed` it fixes the background in relation to the window. So you would then need to adjust the `background-position` of your images so they appear in the right place. If you replace your `background`properties with the css below it will line up properly.

```
div.backgroundboxleft {
    background-image: url("/images/back_1.png");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 0 44px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div.backgroundboxright {
    background-image: url("/images/back_2.png");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 1323px 44px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/6fZ96/embedded/result/

To clarify `background-attachment:fixed` stops the background from scrolling with the window. So if your viewport is too small and you have to scroll horizontally or vertically the background will not move (i.e. it will be overlapped). More information can be found [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-attachment).

Comment: That works, but now the top and bottom of the side images get cut off by the top and bottom divs, which probably wasn't what he had in mind.

Comment: @edwin: That is the nature of a fixed background. The bottom is getting cut off because of the height of the `div`. It would need to be made larger if it were to all be seen when the window is scrolled.

Comment: Doesn't quite work - I can't see the right image now, and I still need to scroll left. Maybe try `.art-sheet { margin-left: 503px; }`? At least that will fix the main content moving around.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to look at the div's height. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @edwin: You must be on a smaller screen. It works exactly as I would expect. The `background-image`'s are fixed in place. It's fixed relative to the window. So `div.backgroundboxright` is positioned `1323px` from the left of the window, which is why it looks odd when you scroll (because the bg is now positioned off the screen and is not part of the content). As the name suggests, you cannot **fix** the background in place and then be surprised when it doesn't scroll with the page. I don't think `fixed` should be used in this case but I was answering his question as to why it messed up.

Comment: @tw16 and Edwin thanks again for answering.The .art-sheet { margin-left: 503px; } messes up the fix of tw16.I understand that the height of art-sheet div is the one that cuts off the two images.I was thinking if changed the size of bacgroundboxleft and bacgroundboxright with JavaScript in accordance to art-sheet div which loads all the content.

Comment: @alexander: As I explained above in the answer and comments, `background-attachment:fixed` stops the background from scrolling with the window. So if you have to scroll horizontally or vertically the background will not move (i.e. it will be overlapped). The property is doing what it is supposed to do, the margin is not causing the issue. Have a read of this http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-attachment it might help you understand it better. This does however answer your question as to why the layout messes up. If you want to dynamically change the figures I'd ask another question.

Comment: @tw16  Ty very much.I mark my question answered.If you can add the info of the comments to your answer to be more complete :)

Comment: @tw16 I have the same issue in chrome with the Background-size set as cover, so it shouldn't be a position problem.

Comment: My control's background keeps anchored to the control's top-left corner no matter what! I need it to be fixed with the window! background-attachment not working, and NOTHING I try works! Any suggestions?