# Background image won't show in Chrome when I use background-attachment:fixed

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

My site uses three divs that contains testimonials. Each div has a large background image with a fixed background.

I didn't make any changes to the site, but some time in the past two days one of those divs stopped showing its background image in Chrome. **It works perfectly in Firefox and IE.**

The code is completely identical to the other testimonial divs except with a different background image and different text. When I copy the CSS for the other divs, the background image still does not show.

After a lot of trial and error this morning, I've isolated the problem - but it doesn't make any sense to me. The image shows up under these two conditions:

- A media query switches the background-size from "100%" to "auto 100%". However, changing this in the original css for the div does not make the image show up.
- ...OR "background-attachment:fixed" is commented out.

Here's the CSS...

```
.testimonial3 {background: url(http://website.com/backgroundimage.jpg) no-repeat right bottom; 
background-color:#FF5800;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: auto 100%;}
```

...and the HTML

```
<div class="testimonial3">

<p>"My company contacted Company to develop a new user-friendly website. The site looks GREAT and now we continue to utilize Company's SEO services as we move into the future.</p>
<p>John Doe, Professional Services Company, New York</p>

</div>
```

Comment: JSfiddle demo please.

Comment: so many tickets on this subject . have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223196/css-problem-with-background-attachmentfixed

Comment: Thanks for the link, Mihnea. The image is the full size of the screen, the background position is specified, and it works properly in every browser except for Chrome, so I don't think the solution to that question applies in this instance.

Comment: this problem is also in relation with the background-position: when I change it from bottom to top, it works perfectly. And also in relation with the viewport size: if the viewport is wide enough, the bg shows up, if I decrease the viewport-width, it is disappearing.