# float div with fixed background in same line error

Tags: html, css

i've got two divs with fixed background image... what i want is that the divs should float one left and one right...here the code:

```
<div class="stop2" style="height: 600px;" data-natural-height="900" data-natural-width="1400">

    <div  id="stop2SX"></div>
    <div  id="stop2DX"></div>

</div>
```

and the css:

```
#stop2SX{


    background-image:url(Stop2_small_SX.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position-x: 0px;
    background-position-y: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;

}
#stop2DX{
    background-image:url(Stop2_small_DX.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position-x: 0px;
    background-position-y: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0px;
    float: right;
    display: inline;
}
```

the second div is not visible

here's the pic:

[image]

Comment: can u make a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: what's the problem with this solution ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avQNLz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/34/

**CSS**

```
#stop2SX{
    background-image:url(http://placehold.it/350x150);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
#stop2DX{
    background-image:url(http://placehold.it/350x150);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why but the problem create `background-attachment: fixed;` on both divs so i had to remove it.

Comment: i wanted to be fixed so when i scroll down the background keeps the position

Comment: i know that the problem is background-attachment: fixed; so i write to stackoverflow!!! removing one attribute isn't the solution

Comment: also, i added two images so when zoom out the images float each side to prevent different resolution to have problem...

Comment: Let me figure it out.

Comment: So this is what i got so far https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/35/. `background-attachment: fixed;` sets background for whole `window` and not for div so you can read it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223196/css-problem-with-background-attachmentfixed

Comment: If you set `background-size: cover;` you will see that it will be set for whole window and not for divs

Comment: Awesome, glad i could help.

Answer (score -1):

div with `float:right` must be first

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10155083)

Comment: @ebramtharwat man, i say, that div with float:right must be first, to achieve author's goal. what's the problem?

Comment: becuase you just post a code without any explaination of it .. this could be post as a comment

Answer (score -1):

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpzevzLk/) for example on how to align two divs.

```
#stop2SX{
  background-color:red;
  width: 50%;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
}
#stop2DX{
  background-color:blue;
  width: 50%;
  height:100%;
  float: right;
  }
```

You should float them accordingly and don't forget to put a width on them.

UPDATE:

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5smmq4pw/) .. Is this what you are trying to achieve then?