# My background-attachment: fixed is not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my #main div scroll on top of my #main2 div. I positioned both absolutely and used background-attachment: fixed on #main2, but the intended effect does not seem to be working. BY "scroll on top" I mean that when you scroll down on the mouse, #main should scroll down towards a fixed #main2. #main2 should be like the background image of the body while #main1 fluidly scrolls down to the bottom of the body.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJLzP_4bg3o @7:50 is what I am trying to replicate.

```css
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#main {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: red;
} 

#main2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    top: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype HTML>
<head>
   <html lang="en"
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clc.css">
    <title>CLC Website</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">        
    </div>
    <div id="main2">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by scroll on top. maybe you can clarify? also is attachment fixed necessary?

Comment: What is the "intended effect"? Your code does exactly what it is supposed to do regarding the snippet you provided.

Comment: `background-attachment` works if an `background-image` is specified. Refer this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment

Comment: Question is not clear at all, `background-attachment` works on `background-image` neither did you mentioned any particular situation nor even have shown it with some image workout.. with bgColor, its working absolutely fine.

Comment: Also check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223196/css-problem-with-background-attachmentfixed

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity. I edited the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

Check this if help you out.

```
<head>
    <style> 
        .main { height: 300px;  width: 300px;background-color: blue;    background-repeat: no-repeat;   background-attachment: fixed;
position: fixed;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div style="background-color: red; height: 3000px; width: 300px"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `#main` to `position: fixed;` and give `z-index: 1;`

```css
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#main {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 1;
} 

#main2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    top: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype HTML>
<head>
   <html lang="en"
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clc.css">
    <title>CLC Website</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">        
    </div>
    <div id="main2">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the parallax effect, I just changed the background-color to background-image and it works fine now.